# Проблема с добавлением в массив JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Получаю URL-параметры и хочу занести их в массив `result`. Но не понимаю, почему массив по итогу пустой?

Если же отображать в `alert` например `url_search_split_split[0]`, то всё работает и выдаются ключи.

```js
function getUrlParams() {
  var result = [];

  var url_search = window.location.search;
  var url_search_split = url_search.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&');

  for (i = 0; i < url_search_split.length; i++) {
    var url_search_split_split = url_search_split[i].split('=');

    result[url_search_split_split[0]] = url_search_split_split[1];
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(getUrlParams());
```

Comment: Если смотреть результат в консоли - результат интереснее: `["": undefined]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому, что в JavaScript индексами массива не могут быть строки. А если вы хотите получить ассоциативный массив, то вам нужен не массив, а объект

```js
function getUrlParams() {
  var result = {};

  var url_search = "?q=test&rlz=1C1GCEU_ruUA889UA889&oq=test&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61j69i60l2.2743j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
  var url_search_split = url_search.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&');

  for (i = 0; i < url_search_split.length; i++) {
    var url_search_split_split = url_search_split[i].split('=');

    result[url_search_split_split[0]] = url_search_split_split[1];
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(getUrlParams());
```

Comment: Странно, но у меня и с массивом работает

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, благодарю! Работает!

Comment: @ДавидМанжула Что у вас работает? Еще раз: в JS ключами в массиве могут быть только целые числа начиная с 0. Причем в массиве не может быть пропусков

Comment: @ДавидМанжула, массив является расширением базового типа объекта `object`, поэтому да, технически массив может содержать свойства со строковым ключом. **Но:** 1. эти ключи не являются индексами элементов массива (значения этих свойств, соотв., не являются перечисляемыми элементами массива); 2. добавлять объектные свойства экземплярам массива считается _очень_ плохой практикой (т.к. массивы не для таких целей, для подобного есть гораздо более подходящие `Object` и `Map`).

Comment: @yar85, ммммм, весьма интересно. Не итерирует и не отображает в `JSON.stringify`. Наверное не замечал такого, потому что в DevTools нормально отображает